# redirecting subdomain to subfolders with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, mod-rewrite

i am trying to redirect a subdomain to a subfolder
i have 3 sub-domains pointing to a folder named "test" placed on the root (/test)

```
    subdomain1.mysite.com
    subdomain2.mysite.com
    subdomain3.mysite.com

in test i have 3 folders `/test/subdomain1 , /test/subdomain2, /test/subdomain3`

what i want is that:
when i go to subdomain1.mysite.com it should be reading from: /test/subdomain1
when i go to subdomain2.mysite.com it should be reading from: /test/subdomain2
when i go to subdomain3.mysite.com it should be reading from: /test/subdomain3

here is my htaccess used - placed in the folder "/test" and i think here is the problem!!:

    Options -Indexes
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.mysite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain1/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain2/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain3/$1 [L,QSA]
    </IfModule>

i am getting a "500 Internal Server Error" when accessing any subdomain...

does RewriteBase works in subfolders ? if not placed the root ?

any idea?

thanks
```

Comment: is the `<br/>` on this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain2/$1 [L,QSA]<br/>` an error here or is that in your htaccess file?

Comment: Ah no Matt its a spelling mistake i removed it !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 500 error is because you haven't escaped your `.` in the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.mysite.com$ [NC]
```

should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: thank you Matt for your help!!
i tried to escape the dots but still having the same error!!
my domain contains a "-" does that means anything ?

Comment: the htaccess is placed in the folder "test" do i put it on the root level and change the RewriteBase ?

Comment: Move the htaccess to the root and try escaping your hyphen as well.

Comment: i made sure that mode rewrite is working by adding 
`RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^google\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]`

Comment: Hey Matt ! its working as you said !!! but if only i have an index.php file in the folder subdomain1,subdomain2,subdomain3!!
but in subdomain2 i am getting a 500 internal server error,because i do not have an index, i will have a list of folders containing images...

Answer (score 0):

There is an error...

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain1/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain2/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain3/$1 [L,QSA]
```

last 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain3/$1 [L,QSA]
```

subdomain2 instead of subdomain3