# redirecting subdomain to subfolders not containing an index.php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, mod-rewrite

i am getting a 500 internal server error with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^data\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ data/$1 [L,QSA]
```

-----------------???
when i replace the RewriteRule line by the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ data/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it works , but in real case i will not have an index.php in the folder, i will have folders containing images...

Any Idea??
original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324970/redirecting-subdomain-to-subfolders-with-htaccess/8325344#8325344)

Comment: A 500 internal error should have more information in the error log. What does it say there for the requests?

Comment: i dont have an error_log file in that folder!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rules are looping, each time the URI is rewritten, it is reapplied to all the rules until the rules don't change the URI. So when you request **/something**, the rewrite rule gets applied and the URI is changed to **/data/something**, then it is resent through the rewrite engine, then it gets rewritten to **/data/data/something** then **/data/data/data/something** etc. Eventually mod_rewrite will reach its recursion limit and return a 500 server error. You can try a few things to end the loop, assuming you really only want a single **/data/** to be appended in the beginning. You can add one of the following before your `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/data
```

or

```
RewriteCond $1 ^/data
```